# Network of subdomains

Tags: subdomains

We, as a commercial reseller company, would like to create a website that would allow us to help our customers to sell more of our products.

Our goal would be to create a domain (something.com) and have multiple subdomains (customer1.something.com, customer2.something.com, and so on). This would be pretty straight forward but we would like to have something simple to be applied as we would like to minimise the space occupied in our server.

Having that said, the subdomain websites would differ from the domain website:
– on the banner, as instead of having our banner, we would create a banner for each customer;
– on a contact page, as we would create a specific contact page for each customer;

Furthermore, as these websites would act as online shops, the orders, placed using a shopping cart, should be directed to us and we would have to have the indication from which subdomain the order came (so we can ship the products to the applicable customer).

As per before mentioned, we would like to avoid to duplicate the full website due to space usage on our server. We would like to have the products and photos database shared between the domain and the subdomains.

Is there any plugin on WordPress that would achieve this objective?

Thank you for your help.